# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints: FBSDKLoginButton

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, objective-c, constraints

He creado un botón de tipo FBSDKLoginButton al que le he dado una serie de constraints, entre ellas, una altura. Este es el error que me salta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe como puedo evitar que me salte esta alerta en mi consola? No es un fatal error, pero sí quiero saber qué esta pasando.

Comment: Lo mas normal: Que tengas 2 constraints de altura diferentes o que tengas una de altura y ademas otras dos desde el top y en el bottom hacia otros sitios que chocan con la altura.

Comment: He añadido una respuesta, Spidvmp. Puede ser por lo que tu has dicho en otro caso, pero, en este caso se debe al tamaño fijo del botón de Facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rapidamente he encontrado la solución: el problema, tal y como indica Facebook en su [documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4x#4180to4190):

> *The FBSDKLoginButton UI has changed in 4.19.0. Instead of "Log in with Facebook", the button now displays "Continue with Facebook". The button color is changed to #4267B2 from #3B5998. The button height is now fixed at 28 due to use of smaller font size and paddings around a larger Facebook logo.*

Se debe a que han establecido un tamaño fijo en los botones de log in del FBSDK. Por tanto, simplemente cambiando la constante puesta en mi Interface Builder, ha solucionado ese molesto alert.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]